# bcrypt compare takes more than a minute to complete

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I just implemented user authentication for my REST API and used bcrypt for password hashing. When creating a user I basically do

```
const passwordSalt: string = await genSalt(12);
const passwordHash: string = await hash('pAsSwOrD', passwordSalt);
```

and save the hash to the database. Later on when a user signs in I compare the provided password with the database password hash.

```
const passwordMatches: boolean = await compare('wRoNg pAsSwOrD', user.passwordHash);
```

I know that the compare function should be slow to help against brute force attacks. But the compare function takes more than a minute to complete. Users won't wait for that to complete. So is something wrong with my code?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This has nothing to do with brute force. Also the code shouldn't take that time to compare. Have you checked the query time?

Comment: yes, the debugger jumps to the password comparison instantly. but then it takes one minute to move on. The whole HTTP call takes 1 minute and 4 seconds (I tested it with postman)

Comment: Do you have the source file available?

Comment: Yes, this is the code that gets executed when signing in https://github.com/matthiashermsen/nest-api/blob/master/src/authentications/authentications.service.ts#L55

Comment: btw. if you would like to play around, this is my .env file configuration `SERVER_PORT = 3000

DATABASE_TYPE = postgres
DATABASE_HOST = localhost
DATABASE_PORT = 5432
DATABASE_USERNAME = postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD = postgres
DATABASE_NAME = api
DATABASE_LOGGING = true
DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE = true

NODE_ENV = development

AUTHENTICATION_SALT_ROUNDS = 12
TOKEN_SECRET = secret
TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS = 36000`

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this was so slow?

Comment: What I have noticed is that the number of rounds provided in the `.genSalt()` method really affects the speed of the `.compare()` method. When i use 12 or 16 rounds, it takes a really long time, but with the default rounds of 10 (`bcryptjs`), it is actually way faster.

Try to reduce the rounds to the default 10, and it might help.

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt with a cost of 12 should not take more than 1 second on any real computer.

That must mean that that the bcrypt implementation you're using is not very well written.

A good way to check that it's not bcrypt, try the call with different costs:

| Cost | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 67 ms |
| 4 | 135 ms |
| 5 | 270 ms |
| 6 | 560 ms |
| 7 | 1,130 ms |
| 8 | 3,250 ms |
| 9 | 7,500 ms |
| 10 | 15,000 ms |
| 11 | 30,000 ms |
| 12 | 60,000 ms |

Answer (score 0):

Use less salt rounds like 2 to 5.

```
const saltRounds = 2;
```